# Robotframework. I cannot make the login Username to be typed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I wrote a simple Robotframework program to make a LinkedIn page to fail by entering an invalid user name and password. Execution stops in the Login page with cursor in Username field. It doesn't type the invalid email id /password. I appreciate anyone's help. Is it a web driver issue or my code is not correct? Thank you.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Browser}        ie
${SiteUrl}        https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login

*** Test Cases ***
LoginTest
    Open Browser to the Login Page
    Enter User Name
    Enter Password
    Click Signin

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser to the Login Page
    open browser    ${SiteUrl}    ${Browser}
    Maximize Browser Window

Enter User Name
    Input Text  name=session_key-login  novalid@hotmail.com

Enter Password
    Input Text    name=session_password  nopwd

Click Signin
    click button    name = signin
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your username and password locators are incorrect. You can use id tags like this:

```
Enter User Name
    Input Text    id=session_key-login       novalid@hotmail.com

Enter Password
    Input Text    id=session_password-login  nopwd
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed it to id and now I can see the  User name entered  and password entered.  At least is an improvement. Still I cannot understand why I cannot use the name as locator. In the Library documentation suppose I am allowed to.

Comment: name fails because it is "session_key" and in your example you were trying "session_key-login".